# Eloquent whereHas Relationship with constraint on particular related Entity

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Consider having two models **User**, and **Book** the last one has a status column that can obtain different string values `active`, `inactive`, `deleted`, so the user can have multiple books and the book belongs to the user.

how could I get only users that have their last book status = 'inactive'?

The SQL Query for the behavior is given below:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `users`
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `books`
    WHERE
        `books`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` AND `books`.`status` = 'inactive' AND `books`.`id` =(
        SELECT
            nested.`id`
        FROM
            `books` AS nested
        WHERE
            nested.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
        ORDER BY
            nested.`created_at` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
)
```

I'm using Laravel 5.6

Comment: Do you have your models and relationships set up in Laravel? You should have a `User` and `Book` model, then you can do `User::whereHas('books', function($query){ ... })->get();` (you'll have to determine the inner logic to get the last book's status)

Comment: any idea to make this SQL query works on eloquent?

Comment: Technically, that is Eloquent. If you don't want to use Models (which is silly if you're using Laravel), then you could do a `DB::table()->select(DB::raw())->get();` and paste your whole query in there... But try to use Laravel before resorting to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create additional relationship in `User` model that returns wanted result. Basically you need 1-1 relationship for this.

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function inactiveBookStillLatestPerUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Book::class)->where(['status' => 'inactive', 'id' => function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $nested) {
        $nested->from('books as nested')
            ->selectRaw('max(id)')
            ->whereRaw('nested.user_id = books.user_id');
    }]);
}
```

Then in somewhere in code (i.e. controller) you call it with

```
$users = User::has('inactiveBookStillLatestPerUser')->get();
// or if books are needed too
// $users = User::has('inactiveBookStillLatestPerUser')->with(['inactiveBookStillLatestPerUser'])->get();
```

I used `id` latest order [`max(id)`] in subquery to avoid unwanted result if one user made multiple books batch insert at same point of time and when all those books would have same time of insert so latest per created_at wouldn't be most accurate, maybe. But you can do that similarly, instead:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function inactiveBookStillLatestPerUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Book::class)->where(['status' => 'inactive', 'created_at' => function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $nested) {
        $nested->from('books as nested')
            ->selectRaw('max(created_at)')
            ->whereRaw('nested.user_id = books.user_id');
    }]);
}
```

Maybe second example is ok, but first example with `id` would work fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

```php
User::where('your-conditions')
    ->whereHas('books', function($query) {
        $query->where('books.status', '=', 'inactive')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->first();
    })->get();
```

Comment: While your code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps.